# Unable use Keywords for AdView from AdMob in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, admob

I am using [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#wp) for windows phone 8 in one of my apps.

The xaml looks like:

```
<GoogleAds:AdView Name="AdView" Height="80" Width="480" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
                  AdUnitID="MyAdunitId" Format="Banner" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                          />
```

This one loads ads. Now,I am trying to fetch ads based upon `Keywords` property. The code looks like this:

```
AdRequest rq = new AdRequest();
rq.Keywords = keywordsForAds.ToArray();
AdView.LoadAd(rq);
```

However, the ads displayed are not based on the keywords that I specify, no matter what. Also, in the `ReceivedAd` event, I notice that the `AdView.Parameter.Keywords` 
is an empty array of strings.

Am I missing some thing in using the `Keywords` here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    AdRequest rq = new AdRequest();
    string[] Keywords = { "Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3", "Keyword4" };
    rq.Keywords = Keywords;
    AdView.LoadAd(rq);
```